# Set a selected option of a dropdown list control not working

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML mark-up:

```
<select id="selectDays" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDays"
        ng-options="value.id as value.name for value in searchDays" ng-change="selectChange()">
</select>
```

searchDays is json array defined in $scope:

```
    $scope.searchDays = [{ name: "30 Days", id: 30 }, { name: "60 Days", id: 60 }, { name: "90 Days", id: 90 }];
```

I want the third option to be selected i.e. 90 Days, I am using this code but it's not working:

```
    //select 90 Days
    $scope.selectedDays = $scope.searchDays[2];
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `id` property:

```
$scope.selectedDays = $scope.searchDays[2].id
```

Comment: Thanks brother, I am actually new to angular, this helped me :)